# How to select MAX from varchar column in a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

In a table there are two columns 'art' and 'price' both in varchar. The 'price' is formatted as currency.

To find the highest price together with the article I used:

```sql
SELECT art, price FROM books 
WHERE price = (SELECT MAX(CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(price, ',', ''),'.','') AS INT)) 
FROM books)
```

It won't work. Please, what is wrong?

Comment: What does "it won't work" mean? Include the error message or other unexpected output in your question.

Comment: And why is price stored as varchar and not as a numeric value?

Comment: Have a look at the MySQL documentation about [cast()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast).  Your target type `INT` is not supported here.

Comment: 'is formatted as currency.' - Does this mean there is a currency symbol included ($,£ etc)

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare the price to the price.  So, one method is:

```
SELECT b.art, b.price
FROM books b
WHERE b2.price = (SELECT b2.price
                  FROM books b2
                  ORDER BY REPLACE(REPLACE(b2.price, ',', ''), '.', '') + 0 DESC
                  LIMIT 1
                 );
```

You should be storing the value as a `decimal`/`numeric` type -- the `.` suggests that you have a decimal portion.  I would not recommend removing it, so:

```
WHERE b2.price = (SELECT b2.price
                  FROM books b2
                  ORDER BY REPLACE(b2.price, ',', '') + 0 DESC
                  LIMIT 1
                 );
```

This replaces the explicit conversion with implicit conversion -- because MySQL has arcane rules for types with `CAST`.

Finally, this can also be handled using window functions:

```
select b.*
from (select b.*,
             rank() over (order by REPLACE(b2.price, ',', '') + 0 desc) as seqnum
      from books b
     ) b
where seqnum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

When you cast to integer, use either `SIGNED` or `UNSIGNED` as target.

```
SELECT art, price FROM books 
WHERE price = (SELECT MAX(CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(price, ',', ''),'.','') AS SIGNED)) 
FROM books)
```

You should store numeric values as numeric instead of strings.